# Оператор continue

Tags: python

Подскажите, нужен ли в этой ситуации оператор continue (Python)?

```
listt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for elem in listt:
    if elem % 2 == 0: # (чётное ли число)
        print('число', elem, 'чётное')
    else:
        continue
```

Нужен ли в этой ситуации continue, если и без него программа работает корректно? В каких ситуациях тогда нужно использовать continue?

Comment: Можно без него, continue если вам в текущей строчке кода нужно перейти сразу к следующей итерации в цикле, не дожидаясь исполнения всех оставшихся команд.

Comment: В вашем случае кроме команды continue дальше нет ничего, поэтому вызывать ее бессмысленно.

Comment: пример когда нужно: допустим вам требуется пройти циклом и обработать все числа, которые не делятся на 4.и тогда поможет if chislo%4==0: continue а ниже вычисления

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` полезен в тех случаях, когда есть длинный блок кода, чтобы уменьшить отступы в программе. Например:

```
for ...:
    if условие:
        # длинный 
        # блок
        # кода
        # ну очень
        # длинный
```

Можно заменить на:

```
for ...:
    if не условие:
        continue

    # длинный 
    # блок
    # кода
    # ну очень
    # длинный
```

Когда в программе и так много отступов это бывает полезно.